# How to define the set of all finite words $\mathbb{W}$ from an alphabet $\Sigma$ using set union and Cartesian product?

Tags: summation, notation

I wish to define the set of all words $\mathbb{W}$ from the alphabet $\Sigma$.

For instance if $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$, then the words are $\mathbb{W}:=\{ \varnothing, 0,1,00,...\}$

Can I write

$$
\mathbb{W}:=\bigcup_{i=0}^? \Sigma^i
$$

In this case I get all words as tuples.

$(0,1,0)$ would be a word and I get shorten the notation to $(0,1,0)=010$ which is a binary word.

Problem is I do not know how to capture the notion that the words are finite, whilst still grabbing all of them? What do I replace the quotation mark with?

---

$$
\mathbb{W}:=\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty \Sigma^i
$$

In this case, it seems I get an uncountable set.

---

$$
\mathbb{W}:=\bigcup_{i=0}^n \Sigma^i
$$

In this case, it seems I am missing all words greater than n.

---

$$
\mathbb{W}:=\bigcup_{i=0}^{<\infty} \Sigma^i
$$

Is less than infinity acceptable notation for a sum greater than any natural number but not infinite?

Comment: You might have better luck defining your unions in terms of which set contains $i$. For example, you could take the union for all $i\in \mathbb{Z}^+$

Comment: In set theory we use the notation $\Sigma^{ \lt \omega}$ to capture the concept of all finite sequences.

Comment: "In this case, it seems I get an uncountable set." Not true: like for series, we write $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 1/i^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider a binary alphabet $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ we can represent the set of all $2^i$ binary words of length $i>0$ as
\begin{align*}
\Sigma^i:=\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_i):x_j\in \Sigma, 1\leq j\leq i\}
\end{align*}

We often use a special symbol $\varepsilon:=\sum^0$ to denote the *empty* word of length $0$.

> - The set $\mathbb{W}$ of *all* binary words having finite length can be written as
>   \begin{align*}
>   \color{blue}{\mathbb{W}=\bigcup_{i\geq 0}\Sigma^i=\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}\Sigma^i=\varepsilon\cup\Sigma^{1}\cup\Sigma^{2}\cup\cdots}\tag{1}\\
>   \end{align*}
>
>   Each representation in (1) is admissible and describes the set of all binary words with finite length. Here we have a countable union of sets $\Sigma^i$ each with finite size $\left|\Sigma^i\right|=2^i$ which is a countable set.

The upper bound $\infty$ in $\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}$ means that we do not have any *finite* upper bound. Nevertheless the index $i\in\mathbb{N}$ for all indices $i$ under consideration.

*Hint:* We have a similar situation when considering an infinite sum
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i\geq 0}a_i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i=a_0+a_1+a_2+\cdots
\end{align*}
which is a sum of countably many summands $a_i, i\in\mathbb{N}$.